# Cannot grid the second subfigure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Im using the matplotlib and following code grids only the second subfigure, not the first one. I cannot figure out the problem.
What do you think the problem is and how to grid both figures?

Thanks

```
ep = np.linspace(1, 500, 500)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
plt.grid()
axs[0].set_title('me')
axs[0].set(xlabel='you', ylabel='me')
axs[0].plot(ep, me_es)
axs[1].set(xlabel='ty', ylabel='no')
axs[1].set_title('sec')
axs[1].plot(ep,me_es)
plt.tight_layout(pad=1, w_pad=1.5, h_pad=2.0)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.4, 10.8)
```

Here is the figure Im getting.[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.grid()` is equivalent to `plt.gca().grid()` ([see here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.1/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L2614-L2616)). `gca()` stands for "get current axis" ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html)). So it will grid the current axis which is the last one created: here the second one. In other words, in your case `plt.grid()` = `axs[1].grid()`

Adding `axs[0].grid()` should work for you.

Comment: That's it. I appreciate much.